# Fix a Cucumber runner cant find Junit 5 tests error eclipse?

Tags: java, cucumber, junit5

Im running some cucumber feature files.

In eclipse when I run a feature file individually, it works.
But when I try to run the Cucumber runner class the error message I get is that

"No tests found with JUint5"

The issue persists after restarting eclipse or cleaning the project.

It returns a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
 features = "path/to/features"
 ,glue={"com.pathto.steps"}
 )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Any ideas how to solve it please?

It running in the test dir of a spring boot application

Comment: `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` is JUnit 4 only. So you have to look for Junit 5 or Junit platform support, which as far as I know is in the making but I don't know if it's done yet. Alternatively you can include JUnit Vintage (i.e. JUnit 4 support for the JUnit platform) and use `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` with it.

Comment: Did you find any solution?